# Output files in visual studio setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, post-build-event

In Visual Studio 2010 solution I included the project and Setup for project. In postbuild for the project, there are some steps, for example - the obfuscation on `$ (TargetPath).` But Setup takes the files from `obj` folder.

Questions two:

  - How can customize the setup, to take the files from the
  `bin/debug`
  or
  `bin /release`
  folders?

  - Or how to specify a folder in postbuild
  `obj/$(ConfigurationName)`
  ?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried Add -> Project Output?

Comment: What technology you use for your "Setup"? Do you use WIX?